# How to get data from all RecyclerView EditTexts

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView in my app which contains two buttons.One adds an item (two EditTexts) to the RecyclerView, and the other is for getting the values entered in the EditTexts and sending them to another activity.
The number of items in the RecyclerView are based on user's needs. And I don't know how to get All the values user entered in those EditTexts and send them to another activity.
(the EditTexts only get numberDecimal type and i want to do some math on the values)

**Update:** Added EntryData and MainActivity Classes.

**Adapter:**

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.DataViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<EntryData> datas = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public DataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_surface, parent, false);
        return new DataViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindData(datas.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return datas.size();
    }

    public static class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private EditText lengthEditText;
        private EditText diameterEditText;
        public DataViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            lengthEditText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_length);
            diameterEditText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_diameter);
        }
        public void bindData(EntryData entryData) {
            lengthTextView.setText(entryData.getLength());
            diameterTextView.setText(entryData.getDiameter());
        }
    }
    public void addData(EntryData entryData) {
        datas.add(entryData);
        notifyItemInserted(datas.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

**EntryData Class:**

```
    public class EntryData {

    private String length;
    private String diameter;

    public String getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(String length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public String getDiameter() {
        return diameter;
    }

    public void setDiameter(String diameter) {
        this.diameter = diameter;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setupViews();
    }

    private void setupViews() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView= findViewById(R.id.rv_main_data);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
        final DataAdapter adapter= new DataAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        Button addDataButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_main_addData);
        addDataButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EntryData entryData = new EntryData();
                adapter.addData(entryData);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**item_surface.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="2">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_length"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="length"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"

        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_diameter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:hint="diameter"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"

        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you update your question to include the EntryData class file?

Comment: And the code of the class that contains the recyclerview

Comment: @Larpee Added the class

Comment: @karique Done...

Comment: Are you open to using two-way Android data-binding? It would probably make this much easier.

Comment: And could you also include the code from R.layout.item_surface.xml?

Comment: There isnt any EditText in your code. So where are you talking about?

Comment: @greenapps when user clicks on the button an item containing two EditTexts gets added to the RecyclerView. I added the xml code to the question. take a look

Comment: `diameterTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_diameter);` ??? What kind of TextView is that? And where is the EditView?

Comment: @greenapps oh sorry the correct code is like this :
diameterEditText= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_diameter);
those are EditTexts not TextViews. i just corrected them in the question

Comment: @Larpee Done. take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is the same as the one posted by @MarcosVasconcelos. Here's some code:

In DataViewHolder class:

```
public void bindData(final EntryData entryData) {
        lengthTextView.setText(entryData.getLength());
        diameterTextView.setText(entryData.getDiameter());

        lengthTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                entryData.setLength(charSequence.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        diameterTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                entryData.setDiameter(charSequence.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
    }
```

As you can see, all you have to do is set a TextWatcher on each of the EditTexts. In the `onTextChanged` method, you assign the EditText's current text to the correct EntryData.

In DataAdapter class:

```
public List<EntryData> getData() {
    return datas;
}
```

Getter method for the `datas` List.

And finally, all you have to do is add a Button to the MainActivity and set an OnClickListener on it that gets the `datas` List from the adapter and then gets the necessary values from each EntryData object, like so:

```
private void setupViews() {
    // Your other code

    Button listDataButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_listData);

    listDataButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            List<EntryData> data = adapter.getData();

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                EntryData entryData = data.get(i);

                builder.append(i)
                        .append("\n")
                        .append("Diameter: ")
                        .append(entryData.getDiameter())
                        .append("\n")
                        .append("Length: ")
                        .append(entryData.getLength())
                        .append("\n");
            }

            Log.i("MainActivity", builder.toString());
        }
    });
```

**Edit:** Brief explanation of `StringBuilder`:

The `StringBuilder` class is used to improve perfomance when concantenating large numbers of Strings.
You use it as follows:

1. Initialization: `StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();`. You can also include an intial String or CharSequence in the constructor, or specify the capacity.
2. Concatenation: You can insert new items to the builder by using `builder.append()`. This method accepts not only Strings, but also other data types such as `int`, `char`, and so on.
3. Convert it to a String by using `builder.toString()`.

Refer to [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) and [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for more information.

Comment: Can you give me a brief explanation how the `StringBuilder` works?

Comment: @Hamed I updated my answer with the answer to your question and a couple of useful links. Feel free to ask any other questions you might have

Comment: As i said in the main question, i want to do some math on the datas in another Activity and show the result in a TextView. I passed the `builder.toString()` to the next activity using `intent.putExtra`. But how can I extract those numbers and do what i want to them?

Answer (score 3):

Add a TextWatchListener to the EditText (at bindData) so it keep the relative EntryData of itself updated for the field you are editing, this will keep the data on the objects.

With the objects updated you just need to loop the Adapter#datas field as a List and do what you want with all values.